# PHPExcel Remove cell (column) removeColumn() not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

i created export PHPExcel, but here i want to remove cell "A" here is piece of my code

```
  $spareparts = $this->spareparts_m->getDataSpareparts();
    if ($spareparts) {
        foreach ($spareparts as $key => $sparepart)
        {
            $rownum = $key + $row_geser;
            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $rownum.':W'. $rownum)->getFont()->setSize(10);

            if(isset($flip[1])){
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A' . $rownum, $sparepart['part_no']);
            }else{
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn("A");
            }
        /* Blah..blah.blah */
```

but here `$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn("A");`
 not working and my excel output became like this [screenshot output excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06tm2.png)
any solution please ?

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible that `$flip[1]` is always set?

Comment: no, not always thats why i put `if isset` on there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the **column A** start it with **column B**.

something like this...

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A', 'Sample');
```

To:   `$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B', 'Sample');`

then change the correspond letter to it. you need to set it manually + the row number added from your foreach function.

Comment: nice idea dude, thank you .. but for right now i just set visible false :v